# Meteor.js: Build iOS app for production Where should –server <host>:<port> point?

Tags: meteor

I am building iOS app using `Meteor` + `Cordova` and can't get my head around.. 
Using `Meteor build <path> --server <host>:<port>` command, where should `<host>:<port>` point? What server should I have to build an iOS app? Should I deploy my app to Galaxy first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--server <host>:<port>
```

should point to the location of your Meteor server (so your mobile app knows where to go to connect to your Meteor based backend). For example, if you've deployed your Meteor backend to Galaxy, and have made it available at `https://yourprodurl.com`, then your `--server` setting would look like:

```
--server=https://yourprodurl.com:443
```

Comment: Thanks. p.s. I've tried without the `port` and it also works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran mine like so (building for iOS):

`meteor build ../example-output-folder --mobile-settings settings-staging.json --server https://example-server.meteorapp.com:443`